# CheackBox em um BaseAdapter,como usar?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Ola, estou desenvolvendo meu TCC, e eu não sei como faço pra usar checkbox dentro de um baseAdapter. A minha ideia é, tenho uma janela que me mostra uma lista de pedidos e no final da lista esta o total, cada item dessa lista tem um checkbox, e quero fazer com que quando clico em um checkbox eu traga o preço daquele item e se eu selecionar mais de um, some os valores, porem eu não faço ideia de como fazer isso, procurei na internet, mas nada encontrei.

Aqui esta meu baseAdapater:

```
public class FinalizarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Auxiliar> pedido;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public FinalizarAdapter(Context context, List<Auxiliar> pedido) {
    this.pedido = pedido;
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pedido.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pedido.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        int layout = R.layout.layout_inflater_finalizar_pedido;
        view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        view.setTag(holder);

        holder.tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvItem);
        holder.tvQtd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvQtd);
        holder.cbTotal = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbTotal);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Auxiliar pedi = pedido.get(position);

    holder.tvNome.setText("" + pedi.getNome());
    holder.tvQtd.setText("" + pedi.getQtd());       

    return view;
}   

public class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox cbTotal;
    TextView tvNome;
    TextView tvQtd;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem de criar declarar um *OnClickListener* e associá-lo ao *CheckBox* da *view* de cada uma das linhas da sua lista.
Dentro do método *onClick* ponha o código que pretende executar sempre que o *CheckBox* é clicado.

```
if (view == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    int layout = R.layout.layout_inflater_finalizar_pedido;
    view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    view.setTag(holder);

    holder.tvNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvItem);
    holder.tvQtd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLvQtd);
    holder.cbTotal = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbTotal);

    holder.cbTotal.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;  

            //Código a ser executado quando o checbox é clicado.
        }  
    });  


} else {

    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
```

**Nota:** Dependendo da forma como você gere a sua lista poderá ser necessário que a classe *Auxiliar* tenha de ter um atributo que guarde o estado do *CheckBox*.

Veja [aqui](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) um exemplo